# Look and Feel Difference between design view and application launch

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button

I'm developing a application in visual studio 2010 - VB express edition in Windows 7 x64

I'm new in visual studio and VB.

My question is about the visual of my form.

The visual of my application is diferent when i launch the app - run button - and when i'm on the design view tab - inside visual studio.

in design view:

http://api.photoshop.com/v1.0/accounts/9b66012024ca4fbca3beddffc82e084b/assets/de1def7323514225bfe8c7bc6b9b9f47/renditions/1024.jpg?md=1362888303000

running:
http://api.photoshop.com/v1.0/accounts/9b66012024ca4fbca3beddffc82e084b/assets/7c6d11926450453fad3cf44588f16ca3/renditions/1024.jpg?md=1362888304000

In java you have to set the look and feel. in VB is the same?

thanks.

Comment: Do you call [`Application.EnableVisualStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx)?

Comment: No. I write the line and it worked great. Why the VS don't include this line?

Comment: [It's included in a new C# WinForms Application](http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/174142_program-cs-code-opened.jpg).

Comment: But in vb not. ;) thanks for the quick tip. @ta.speot.is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Application.EnableVisualStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles.aspx) is documented thus:

> This method enables visual styles for the application. Visual styles are the colors, fonts, and other visual elements that form an operating system theme. Controls will draw with visual styles if the control and the operating system support it. **To have an effect, EnableVisualStyles() must be called before creating any controls in the application; typically, EnableVisualStyles() is the first line in the Main function.** A separate manifest is not required to enable visual styles when calling EnableVisualStyles().

Emphasis mine.